# How to adjust inner div container height to fit with others divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please check the demo [link](http://webapplications.co.in/iwitness/index.html) I just want to adjust **Geomap** div's height to 100%. I have tried with this Javascript below but its overflowing with the footer.

```
function handleResize() {
var h = $('html').height();
        $('#map-geo').css({'height':h+'px'});
}
$(function(){
        handleResize();
        $(window).resize(function(){
        handleResize();
    });
});
```

Currently my Html and Body css is

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height:69% !important;
    width:100% !important;  

}
```

Please do help me out to make it fit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: Well, you're setting html to 69% of the viewport height, and then setting #map-geo to match that. That assumes that everything besides #map-geo that takes up height will be 31% of the viewport. That's not always going to be true, depending on the size of the viewport. What you're asking for essentially the same thing as asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space. There are a few options there to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know you should replace :

```
$('#map-geo').css({'height':h+'px'});
```

with :

```
$('#map-geo').css('height',h+'px');
```

And you also need to put the whole function into :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

You can try this, if it works for you :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        function handleResize() {
        var h = $('html').height();
            $('#map-geo').css('height',h+'px');
        }
        handleResize();
    });
```

This alone should resize the element.

Comment: Working like a charm, check the link once again and do let me know whats wrong with my first code ? Also do let me know how to adjust the overlapping Footer while resizing?